# Для чего нужны get и set?

Tags: c#

Можете написать пожалуйста простым языком, для чего нужно в C#.NET?

```
{ get; set;}
```

Comment: @Grundy некрофилией увлекаешься?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, под руку попался :-D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

это геттер и сеттер для свойства:

раньше, даже в java сейчас, для более удобного доступа к инкапсулированым полям классов пользовались парами методов :

```
getField();
setField(value);
```

работали они примерно следующим образом:

```
class SomeClass
{
...
private int _value;
...
public int getValue()
{
    return _value;
}
...
public void setValue(int value)
{
    this._value = value >= 0 ? value : 0;// таким образом не допускали ввода отрицательного значения
}
...
}
```

в С# решили упростить это действие введя геттер - `get{}`, и сеттер `set{}` для свойств

```
...
public int Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set { this._value = value >=0 ? value : 0; }
}
...
```

Таким образом вы можете полностью контролировать операции получения каких-то свойств или их изменения:

- Контролировать изменяемые значения
- Выбрасывать исключения
- Вызывать события
- ...да всё что душе угодно

Более интересный пример:

```
class Light
{
    private bool _isOn = false;
    private bool _isOff = true;

    public bool ON
    {
        get { return _isOn; }
        set 
        { 
            _isOn = value;
            _isOff = !value;
        }
    }

    public bool OFF
    {
        get { return _isOff; }
        set 
        { 
            _isOff = value;
            _isOn = !value;
        }
    }
}
```

Но на самом деле компилятор всё равно преобразовывает эти действия в методы: `get_Value();` и `set_Value(int value);`(не помню точный синтаксис преобразования)

Где-то читал, что Джефри Рихтер критикует эту фичу C#, т.к. это всего лиш синтаксический сахар

> «Лично мне свойства не нравятся, и я
>   был бы рад, если бы их поддержку
>   убрали из Microsoft .NET Framework и
>   сопутствующих языков программирования.
>   Причина в том, что свойства выглядят
>   как поля, на самом деле являясь
>   методами.»
>   [пруф.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_C_Sharp_%D0%B8_Java)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно для чего он!