# Фича Resharper или VS?

Tags: c#, winforms, resharper

У меня есть простое приложение на `WinForms`. Есть различные кнопки: `Add`, `Edit`, `Delete`, `Search` и т. д.
Для этих кнопок я создал свойства, например:

```
public Button ButtonEdit
{
    get { return buttonEdit; }
    set { buttonEdit = value; }
}
```

С помощью свойств я обращаюсь к кнопкам из бизнес-логики, делая их `enabled` в зависимости от условий.

Так вот, после того, как я напишу такое свойство, `Resharper` предлагает сконвертировать его в автоматическое, то есть в такое:

```
public Button ButtonEdit { get; set; }
```

И оно тоже работает правильно.
Как в таком случае понятно, что нужно обращаться к кнопке `buttonEdit`?

Comment: Это синтаксический сахар, компилятор всё равно разворачивает вторую конструкцию в первую. Поле и свойства - вот ключевые слова, читайте. Вот [тут ещё](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/56128/) было.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Я о другом: как в таком случае компилятор понимает, что нужно обращаться к кнопке buttonEdit, а не к кнопке buttonAdd например ?

Comment: Очевидно - по названию.

Comment: Я вот добавил себе свойство такое:
public Button ButtonTest { get; set; }   И компилятор автоматически кнопку не нашёл. А вот добавил так:
public Button ButtonTest
        {
            get { return buttonTest; }
            set { buttonTest = value; }
        }

И появилась подсказка от Решарпера, чтобы сконвертировать в автоматическое св-во, я нажал. И тогда всё работает правильно.

То есть сначала нужно указать нужную кнопку, а потом он её запоминает выходит.

Comment: @Владимир, стоит сравнить состояние автосгенерированного файла формы, вначале и после конвертации решарпером

Comment: @AK вот только если при этом buttonEdit - это созданная через дизайнер кнопка, то дизайнеру WinForms может внезапно не понравится исчезновение сгенерированного поля (решарпер же удаляет поле buttonEdit при такой конвертации)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто.

Если вы используете *автоматическое* свойство (`public Button ButtonEdit { get; set; }`), то поле для этого свойства компилятор генерирует сам, и использует. То есть он при этом не будет использовать ни `buttonEdit`, ни `buttonAdd`. Это автоматически сгенерированное свойство недоступно вам по имени. Но если очень захотеть, его можно найти через рефлексию: компилятор выдумывает для него нечитаемое имя, запрещённое языком, чтобы случайно не попасть в определённое вами имя, относящееся к чему-то другому.

Comment: Спасибо! Но это выдуманное имя создаётся именно после того, как я напишу свойство с телом геттера и сеттера и тогда Решарпер предлагает сконвертировать в автоматическое свойство. И, сделав это, он уже использует своё придуманное имя для той кнопки, которую я указал в теле, верно ?

Comment: @Владимир: Именно так. Выдуманное имя используется только для свойств, определённых с `get; set;`. Для остальных поле не создаётся, и компилятор использует то, что вы написали сами в коде.